# QSerialPort Dropping Bytes

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

I am using QSerialPort to send an receive data in Qt5.5 (windows) and everything works as expected except in one case, when the data sent back contains 0x11. I see this is a special ascii value but would like to read it in as a raw byte.
My setup is as follows:

```
setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
setFlowControl(QSerialPort::SoftwareControl);
setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
```

Later...

```
open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

My reading in a slot connected to readyRead():

```
buffer_.append(readAll());
```

where buffer_ is a QByteArray.

An example packet would be:

```
0xBF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x11 0x00 0x02 0x70
```

and the packet I would receive:

```
0xBF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x02 0x70
```

Comment: Try disabling flow control - QSerialPort::NoFlowControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Kamil Klimek I changed to no flow control and it works.

```
setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

`0x11` and `0x13` are flow control bytes in Sofware Flow mode. This is why `0x11` was "dropped". Using `NoFlowControl` means that you have to control flow by yourself. I.e. you can't write to much data in short time as you will lose it.